Manhwa in which the female lead was brought to a lake or pond by her father and brother in order to heal her
All I remember is that there was a scene at the beginning where the female lead was brought to a lake or pond by her father and brother in order to heal her. So they float her on the lake.
Not sure as well if it's isekai or regression.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

You could improve this Anime Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

i do not recall as well i am sorry! The only further detail i remember is that when she woke up her doting father who works for the emperor like an advisor maybe would take off from work early for her.

@user185833 - I'm sure you can remember more. Was there explicit sex, gore, violence? Was it in black and white or colour? Was it in English or did you read it in another language? Where are you likely to have read it, on paper in a Manga magazine or online?

sorry that’s all i really remember! It’s a manhwa i read online. Definitely no explicit sex, gore, and violence. I think it was in colour.

Did this scene happen in the very first chapter?

yes i think it was the very first chapter! if not exactly that, it is definitely in the first three!

It has been found: “Flower and the Beast”

Could this all perhaps be Hwayeon's dream? Or did Yeonu create this fantasy world in her head to escape her harsh reality?" Hwayeon Ryu, without knowing the cause, falls into a coma at the age of six. Then after 12 long years of her father, Chung Ryu's persistent attempts, she finally opens her eyes. As she wakens from her prolonged sleep, she realizes she not only has her memories but has the memories of someone else's life, Yeonu Lee. Though started at first, as time passes, she manages to adjust to her new life. Then one day, in hope to have lunch with her father, she pays a visit to the palace. But she ends up taking the wrong turn and finds herself in front of the notorious beast, crown prince Muyeong... The story unfolds then, when the soft and delicate flower Hwayeon meets the arrogant and fearless beast, Muyeong.

In the first chapter of this historical manhwa, she woke up on the lake her father and brother brought her to after some light shone down on her.
Available on Pocket Comics.
Thank you all!

Hey, it's great you found it.  You could improve this answer by adding some more, like a short summary.

Will add one shortly! Thank you!
